# Setar valor de outra tabela na coluna da tabela atual (busca valor por ID)

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Vou direto ao assunto.

Minha tabela sql tá assim:

```
id, venda_id, produto_id, qtd_saida, preco_produto
```

Eu gostaria de preencher a coluna **preco_produto** automaticamente quando o **produto_id** for salvo.

> Utilizando as migrates do Laravel, Eu consigo criar colunas calculadas com storedAs, porém não sei se é possível passar uma query dentro do storedAs.  Exemplo do que eu tenho em mente abaixo:

```
$table->decimal('valor_total', 8, 2)->storedAs('select preco from produtos where id=produto_id');
```

Como resolver?

Comment: Crie uma trigger no banco isso que você quer fazer não é suportada pela migration

Comment: Como é feita essa trigger, pode fazer um exemplo?

Comment: Crie um [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers) para assim que um dado for salvo no seu model (que me parece ser de relacionamento). Mas antes de postar a resposta gostaria de saber o nome das tabelas, incluindo a tabela de relacionamentos

Comment: Complementando o comentário do Erlon, segue o link da documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers
Também acho que é a melhor solução